# How to set dynamically many event in fullcalendar in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, fullcalendar

I want to set many event in my fullcalendar

This is my controller:

```
$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/elodieService/reservations/'+$localStorage.idconsommateur+'/m', { params: { "idconsommateur":$localStorage.idconsommateur, fields: "nom,prenom,login,imageJson",format:"json"} }).then(function(result) {

 for (var int = 0; int < result.data.length; int++) {
            console.log(result.data[int].idevenement.titre_annonce);
            var d= new Date(result.data[int].idevenement.date_evenement);


    $scope.uiConfig = {
             calendar:{
                    height: 450,
                    editable: true,
                    lang: 'fr',

                    events: [


                {
                  title: result.data[int].idevenement.titre_annonce,
                  start: d,
                   allDay: true,
                 },
]
}
}
});
```

in my calendar.html

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar">
```

But I always found only the last event in my fullcalendar, I want to find all events in my fullcalendar. What can I do to get this? please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure your calendar out side for loop.

Try this one.

```
$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/elodieService/reservations/'+$localStorage.idconsommateur+'/m', { params: { "idconsommateur":$localStorage.idconsommateur, fields: "nom,prenom,login,imageJson",format:"json"} }).then(function(result) 
{
    var calEvents = [];
    for (var int = 0; int < result.data.length; int++) {
    console.log(result.data[int].idevenement.titre_annonce);
        var d= new Date(result.data[int].idevenement.date_evenement);
        calEvents.push(
        {
        title: result.data[int].idevenement.titre_annonce,
        start: d,
        allDay: true
        }
    );
      }
      $scope.uiConfig = {
          calendar:{
              height: 450,
              editable: true,
              lang: 'fr',
              events: calEvents
          }
      }
});
```

Comment: Hey its updating but the thing is I am using dynamic data loading when view changes, hence it is refreshing, can I stop refreshing the calendar when data changes?